# Using Head.js from an external JS file to load resources

Tags: javascript, head.js, resource-loading

I have an HTML file which includes a JS file in the head tag..

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='lib/head.core.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='custom/my.js'></script>
```

In the *my.js* file I try to load another JS file to use in *my.js*:

```
head.load("custom/foo.js");
```

But anytime I try to execute a function from *foo.js* I get the following error:

[image: Error after calling a function from *foo.js*]

Am I doing something in an incorrect way?

Comment: In case that someone was wondering, I am using the latest production version..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `head.load.min.js`, not `head.core.min.js` to use the `head.load` function.

Comment: @Dropout you can, but it's not needed for the javascript loading-part of headjs.

Comment: Thanks, I was just worried about the conflicts.